# How to import .pem certificate with php SoapClient and CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, soap, codeigniter-2

I have issue with loading .pem certificate to initiate SoapClient PHP.

This issue is the SoapClient can't read .pem certificate on CodeIgniter.

I have created test PHP file without Codeigniter framework to test SOAPClient, and it's worked with me.

PHP code:

```
 $header = array('local_cert' => "newsfile.pem",
        'passphrase' => "Comtrust",
        'exceptions' => FALSE,
        'trace' => true);
```

CodeIgniter SOAP Client Class:

Path: controllers/

```php
class EtisalatPaymentGateway {

    private $client;

    function EtisalatPaymentGateway() {
        // setup the transaction array
        $header = array('local_cert' => APPPATH."controllers/newsfile.pem",
            'passphrase' => "Comtrust",
            'exceptions' => FALSE,
            'trace' => true);
        //var_dump($header);


        $this->client = new SoapClient("https://demo-ipg.comtrust.ae:2443/MerchantAPIX.svc?wsdl", $header);
        //var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    }

    public function getSoapClient(){
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

Payment CI_Controller

```php
<?php

require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/EtisalatPaymentGateway.php');
class Payment extends CI_Controller {

    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //$certificate = $this->load->file(__DIR__."/staging.pem",FALSE);

        // setup the transaction array
        $this->client = new EtisalatPaymentGateway();


    }

    function authorize($customer, $AccountNumber, $amount, $OrderID, $OrderInfo, $OrderName) {
        $body = new StdClass();
        $body->Customer = $customer;
        $body->Language = "en";
        $body->AccountNumber = $AccountNumber;
        $body->Amount = $amount;
        $body->Channel = 'Phone';
        $body->Currency = 'AED';
        $body->ExpiryDate = '2018-04-06T00:00:00';
        $body->OrderID = $OrderID;
        $body->OrderInfo = $OrderInfo;
        $body->OrderName = $OrderName;
        $body->TransactionHint = '';
        $body->VerifyCode = '123';

        $params = array(
                "request" => $body
        );

        $response = $this->client->getSoapClient()->__soapCall("Authorize", array($params));

        $this->responseJson($response);
    }

    private function responseJson($response) {
        /* Print webservice response */
        //print_r($response);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
```

The server response :

> Neither certificate nor password was provided.

I know the issue with the Codeigniter can't read certificate file.

The .pem certificate file exists on /controller path (on the same directory).

Comment: The framework (CodeIgniter) is of zero relevance for this.

Comment: I think you need to verify your path. You have to place your certificate in assets directory (outside application and system directory).

Comment: How to access the .pem file on assets from controller.